# Hosting speed tests?

Tags: web-hosting, optimization, performance

Are there any sites to test the speed of your hosting?  I know there are sites that will tell you why your site is slow, e.g. - YSlow, etc., but how about the speed of bandwidth you get from your hosting provider?

Comment: Are you looking for something that gives you a global view? For instance to see the difference in load time from Texas and Tokyo?

Comment: yes, a global view would be helpful!

Comment: Remember that DNS and static content have a drastic effect on the speed of page loads too.

Answer (score 11):

The Net tab of the Firebug console (remember to disable browser cache).

Resources view of the Web Developer Tools in Chrome/Opera.

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

[HTTP Watch](http://www.httpwatch.com/).

[WebPageTest](http://webpagetest.org).

[Gomez](http://gomez.com/).

We use WebPageTest and Gomez for server tuning, Fiddler if there are any hard to diagnose problems, then the rest for front-end experience testing.

Once you have the level of concurrency and page-views a day the Apache [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) benchmark/stress test tool helps.